# MAAS Node : Automatic Discovery - get [] list?

Tags: maas

adding nodes to the system.
we tried the automatic discovery method.
The command that we typed in "maas-cli maas nodes accept-all"
However, the output is [].
Does this mean that it doesn't recognize nodes?

Enlist nodes via ubuntu server installation cd, and we observe that our server name appeared on enlisting with the maas server. I believe this indicates that the node can communicate the maas server. However, we believe that maas server can't due to above observation (i.e []).

Please verify whether our understanding is right or wrong, and also elaborate what to do to make the server accept all nodes. Note that our goal is to make the node state to change from "commissioning" to "ready" state. We clearly did checked that clocks were synchronized.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The command above is used to Accept & Commission all of the 'Declared' Nodes. This means that the nodes need to be enlisted first in order for you to successfully use that command.

I would recommend you allow the nodes to PXE Boot from MAAS so that they enlist automatically.